# Monotone test and intervals

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, monotone-functions

The monotone test tells us that:\

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ then f is increasing $\iff$ $f'(x)\geq 0$
> $\forall x\in (a,b)$.

**My question:** the theorem holds also if $[a,b]=\mathbb{R}$? I mean I have to require an interval (I mean if I take $1/x$ the domain is an union of intervals...what can I say in this case)?

Comment: To get your answer check the proof. You can find it any book of real analysis. Try to observe where the property of interval (connected subsets of $ \Bbb{R}$ )  is used. Does connectedness of domain required to apply Mean value theorem?

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes!?

Comment: Perhaps add the missing hypotheses:  the function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and everywhere differentiable on $(a,b)$.  Same for $f:(-\infty,\infty)\to \mathbb R$, just assume everywhere differentiable.  If you want some exceptional points then do this:  the function $f$ is continuous everywhere and differentiable at all but countably many points.  Then,  $f'(x)\geq 0$ at every point of differentiability if and only if $f$ is monotone nondecreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I has to be an interval.

For example if we consider:
$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & x \in [-5,-1] \\-1 & x \in[1,5]\end{array}\right.$

It is clear that $f′(x)\geq 0$  $∀x∈[-5,-1]\cup [1,5]$, because at each
interval $f$ is constant. But $f$ is not increasing: $-2,2\in[-5,-1]\cup [1,5]$ and $-2\leq 2$, but $f(-2)=1 \geq -1=f(2).$